# How to test gwtgl code using GWTTestCase in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, gwttestcase

I'm trying to create a test (GWTTestCase) for code that uses e.g. ArrayBuffer or Int32Array from gwtgl, but when running it from eclipse I get an exception and a stack trace.

test method:

```
public void testArray() {
    Int32Array ia = Int32Array.create(new int[] {1, 2, 3});
}
```

result:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Remote test failed at 10.75.20.160 / Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19
  at ...
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null): null
  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
  at ...
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: you're sure it's on this line, while trying to create an array?

Comment: @milan, I'll have to get back to you on that, though I'm pretty sure it's related to the use of gwtgl classes. Either Int32Array or ArrayBuffer.

Comment: @milan, I've verified that it's the Int32Array.create call that's causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

1. Do a GWT compile
2. Try on a different Browser
3. Try clearing browser cache

Comment: The example is a GWTTestCase, run via JUnit in Eclipse. If a browser is involved, I don't know which one, or how to change it.

Comment: did you try what i suggested? even if it is JUnit test case

Comment: GWT compile did not help. I don't know how to try on a different browser. I never picked one in the first place, and no browser is launched afaik.